# Woocommerce redundant data in woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having redundant data in `woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` table in Woocommerce plugin.

Same order have multiple row for same product in a table.

Can any one tell how to remove the redundant data from `woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` table.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if You'd show us your effort.

Comment: I tried to put the group by product_id in sql but it return the rows whose order does not exists. Sql return correct data but continue in conditional statement in php. I am stuck here as I am new in wordpress.